# Django dynamic navigation block in global view

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I want to create a simple navigation block in view, who is global layout view.

I think, I can do it using custom inclusion_tag, but how can I get there current request URL, because I would like determine current URL and set it in navigation block as an active item. How can I get there some global request variable or I need any other approach?

```
#templatetags/menutags.py
@register.inclusion_tag('menu.html')
def show_menu():
    categories = Categories.object.all()
    return {'categories': categories}

#templates/base.html
{% include menutags %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head></head>
<body>
    {% show_menu %}
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>

#templates/view.html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}<div>...</div>{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I think you are mixing up "views" and "templates" in your question. And I do not fully understand what you want and what exactly is not working

Comment: In menu.html I want one of category item set as active. 
base.html I use like layout who extends all other views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('menu.html', takes_context = True)
def show_menu(context):
    categories = Categories.object.all()
    path= context['request'].path
    return {'categories': categories,'path':path}
```

Comment: I've tried the following, but in a context request does not exist

Comment: You need to be using RequestContext to render the template in your view, and have enabled the Request context processor in settings.